I deleted all the elements behind it, and printing is not the result I wanted in react
When I clicked on the element I wanted to delete, the result I wanted was not printed. The key for my current element was not printed, only the keys for the previous elements were printed
And I deleted all the elements that I clicked on and after, oh my god
import { useState } from 'react';

const UtilsGetID = () => {
  return Math.random().toString().slice(-8);
};

const Demo = () => {
  const handleDel = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    const key = e.target.dataset.key;
    const index = dataList.findIndex((item) => {
      console.log('item.key----', item.key, key);
      return item.key === key;
    });
    console.log('index----', index);
    if (index > -1) {
      const item = dataList.splice(index, 1);
      console.log('item----', item);
    }
    setDataList([...dataList]);
  };

  const id = UtilsGetID();
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([
    <div key={id} data-key={id} onClick={(e) => handleDel(e)}>
      xxx,{id}
    </div>,
  ]);
  const addCard = () => {
    const id = UtilsGetID();
    setDataList([
      ...dataList,
      <div key={id} data-key={id} onClick={(e) => handleDel(e)}>
        xxx,{id}
      </div>,
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => addCard()}>addNewEle</button>
      {dataList.map((item) => {
        return item;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Demo;

How to delete only the elements that I have clicked on, like Todolist

Try this out
"import { useState } from 'react';

const UtilsGetID = () => {
  return Math.random().toString().slice(-8);
};

const Demo = () => {
  const handleDel = (key) => {
    // Create a new array without the item to be deleted
 setDataList(prevList => prevList.filter((_, index) => index !== key));

  };
  const id = UtilsGetID();
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([
    <div key={id} data-key={id} onClick={(e) => handleDel(e)}>
      xxx,{id}
    </div>,
  ]);
  const addCard = () => {
    const id = UtilsGetID();
    setDataList([
      ...dataList,
      <div key={id} data-key={id} onClick={(e) => handleDel(e)}>
        xxx,{id}
      </div>,
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => addCard()}>addNewEle</button>
      {dataList.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index} onClick={() => handleDel(index)}>
          {item},{index}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Demo;"

i have updated the handleDel function "its easy to use filter function for removing element from array",
Let me know if this is good
Thank You

setDataList((prevList) => prevList.filter((item) => item.key !== key)); Can meet my expectations

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

code Problem

Keep the state as pure data.
Handle dataList as an object or array in the state, instead of JSX.

problem solving
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([
    <div key={id} data-key={id} onClick={(e) => handleDel(e)}>
      xxx,{id}
    </div>,
  ]);
  
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([{ id: UtilsGetID(), content: "xxx" },]);
  
  
   const handleDel = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    const key = e.target.dataset.key;
    const index = dataList.findIndex((item) => {
      return item.key === key;
    });
    if (index > -1) {
      const item = dataList.splice(index, 1);
      console.log('item----', item);
    }
    setDataList([...dataList]);
  
    const handleDel = (e, id) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    setDataList(dataList.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };


Manage dataList in the state as shown in the code above.
Handle it using the filter method

